# How can I make a function act like a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make `shwOpts.show("fast");` to act when `removeHighlight()` is done?

I thought if I put an anonymous function as an argument in the other it will act as a callback. This didn't work.

```
removeHighlight : function(f) {
        // remove previous highlight.
        var highlight = $('#openid_highlight');
        if (highlight) {
            highlight.replaceWith($('#openid_highlight a')[0]);
        }
    },


 moreOptsLink = $("#more-options-link").click(function () {
              moreOptsLink.detach();
              openid.removeHighlight(function(){$("#show-more-options").show("fast");});
              //shwOpts.show("fast");
              openid.setPref("showMoreOpenIdOptions", !0)
            });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not executing the callback function

```
removeHighlight : function(f) {
    // remove previous highlight.
    var highlight = $('#openid_highlight');
    if (highlight) {
        highlight.replaceWith($('#openid_highlight a')[0]);
    }

    if (typeof(f) === "function") {
        f();
    }
},
```

Comment: It is problably more interesting if you pass an argument in the anonymous function that was made in the body of the other function, that is possible I think?

Comment: @Richard I'm not quite sure if I got you right, but I will give it a try :)  http://jsfiddle.net/WzjDx/

Comment: not exactly what I meant, but I find this syntax interesting-- typeof(c) === "function" && c(); Is this instead of an if block? some kind of shorthand, I have this in my script also, i don't see it a lot! I also see "openid && (openid == 'facebook' ?..etc" -- kind of confusing what exactly it evaluates..

Comment: Yes it's the "tiny" version of `if (typeof(c) === "function") { c(); }` - Maybe you could try to rephrase your comment for me? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should call the callback in the removeHighlight function like this:

```
removeHighlight : function(f) {
    // remove previous highlight.
    var highlight = $('#openid_highlight');
    if (highlight) {
        highlight.replaceWith($('#openid_highlight a')[0]);
        if( typeof f === 'function' ) {
            f();
        }
    }
},


moreOptsLink = $("#more-options-link").click(function () {
     moreOptsLink.detach();
     openid.removeHighlight(function(){
         $("#show-more-options").show("fast");
     });
     openid.setPref("showMoreOpenIdOptions", true);
});
```

By using typeof control, you don't take any error when you don't pass a function as parameter to the function.

Comment: small question: is  the expression !0 another way of saying it's true, I mean why not just say 1?

Comment: it's the same as writing true there :) I just copied it from the question, and I didn't read that part of the code, I just read and fixed the problematic part :)

Comment: I edited the code. Writing !0 is extra work for the computer, since it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
removeHighlight : function(f) {
        // remove previous highlight.
        var highlight = $('#openid_highlight');
        if (highlight) {
            highlight.replaceWith($('#openid_highlight a')[0]);
        }
   //you need to call f
       f()

    },
```